# Coalesce list of links between names into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, coalesce

I currently have two tables used to store relations between entities that look like this:

**Entity_Table**: Contains names and types (*master* or *secondary*) of entities

```
ENTITY_ID  |  ENTITY_NAME  |  ENTITY_TYPE
-----------------------------------------
1          |  'entity_1'   |  'master'
2          |  'entity_2'   |  'secondary'
3          |  'entity_3'   |  'secondary'
...
```

**Links table**: Contains relationship information between entities

```
MASTER_ID  |  SECONDARY_ID
--------------------------
1          |  2
1          |  3
...
```

**Additional information**:

- There are around ~5000 entities, each can have several links, some have no links
- These tables are used by an external c++ code

**What I am looking for**: A query that would return all entities and their linked entities in this format:

```
ENTITY_ID  |  ENTITY_TYPE  |  ENTITY_LINKS
------------------------------------------
1          |  'master'     |  2,3
2          |  'secondary'  |  1
3          |  'secondary'  |  1
...
```

I have tried using `COALESCE` and `JOIN` with little success, any ideas on how I could achieve this?

The links column has to be in a "csv-like" format so it can be used directly by the c++ code behind without massive for loops or having one query per entity which slows things down considerably.

Views are nice too if you know how to put this into a view?

Comment: look up stuff for XML.. plenty of examples out there

Comment: @Harry Any examples ? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: What does XML have to do with this? @Harry

Comment: This has all the tell tales of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of figuring out how to denormalize your data (and likely sql injection vulnerable queries in your C++ code), you should refactor your c++ code to handle sets.

Comment: @gbeaven String_Agg() was introduced in 2017.  The XML/STUFF approach is one of the better methods to aggregate a string,

Comment: @gbeaven see answer below.. should have been stuff .. for xml path

Comment: @Harry Ah, I see, neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will give you what you are after. This uses `STRING_AGG` which requires SQL Server 2017 or newer. If you're using an older version of SQL Server you can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` (which is what I think Harry was talking about above).

```
select e.entity_id, e.entity_type, string_agg(l.secondary_id, ',') as entity_links
from entity_table e
inner join links l on l.master_id = e.entity_id
group by e.entity_id, e.entity_type
union
select e.entity_id, e.entity_type, string_agg(l.master_id, ',') as entity_links
from entity_table e
inner join links l on l.secondary_id = e.entity_id
group by e.entity_id, e.entity_type
```

Think this would give you what you need using `STUFF`.

```
select e.entity_id, e.entity_type, STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + cast(l.secondary_id as varchar(20))
         from links l 
         where l.master_id = e.entity_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') as entity_links
from entity_table e
inner join links l on l.master_id = e.entity_id
group by e.entity_id, e.entity_type
union
select e.entity_id, e.entity_type, STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + cast(l.master_id as varchar(20))
         from links l 
         where l.secondary_id = e.entity_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') as entity_links
from entity_table e
inner join links l on l.secondary_id = e.entity_id
group by e.entity_id, e.entity_type
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to join to links twice with a different on clause then coalesce to get the list of related entities. then use string_agg to put them all on one row, like this:

```
SELECT e1.entity_id,
       e1.entity_type,
       string_agg(COALESCE(l1.secondary_id, l2.master_id), ',')
FROM entities e1
LEFT JOIN links l1 ON (e1.entity_id = l1.master_id AND e1.entity_type = 'master')
LEFT JOIN links l2 ON (e1.entity_id = l2.secondary_id AND e1.entity_type = 'secondary')
GROUP BY e1.entity_id;
```